# how to call _varOp (_varAdd etc) from my program?

Tags: delphi, variants

I'm writing custom variant PhysUnit which is something like VarConv but more advanced, allowing not only adding and subtracting, but also multiplying and dividing units, with real or complex quantities, it works fine, but extremely slow.

Problem is, this custom variant wraps around some other variant (simple types like integer or double, or another custom like VarComplex), so when performing DoAdd, DoSubtract, it firstly checks if both operands have same family (length for example), and then adds quantities converting one of them if neccesary:

```
Left:=Left + Right*multiplier;
```

something like that, here Left and Right are variants.

Compiler turns this line into series of calls:

```
_varCopy(tmp,Left);
_varAdd(tmp,Right*multiplier);
_varClear(Left);
_varCopy(Left,tmp);
_varClear(tmp);
```

while in fact, it would be enough of _varAdd, without allocating/deallocating memory for temporary variant and all these workarounds.

The sad part is: I can't just write _varAdd(Left,Right), it's not linked in VCL.

So the question is: is it possible to call it anyway and make it as "clean" as possible, without nasty calls to direct memory address which might change when compiled with different options or other libraries added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call the underscored functions because the compiler turns the underscore into `@` making it impossible to use it as an identifier.

But assembler functions are allowed to call them. You can use the original declaration and change the `TVarData` into `Variant` so you don't have to cast the Variants all the time.

```
procedure _VarAdd(var Left: Variant; const Right: Variant);
asm
  jmp System.Variants.@VarAdd
end;

procedure _VarSub(var Left: Variant; const Right: Variant);
asm
  jmp System.Variants.@VarSub
end;

begin
  _VarAdd(Left, Right);
end;
```

But using Variants if you want to be fast, isn't the right way. They are very slow and don't have that much help from the compiler's optimizer like integer arithmetic, where `i := i + 1;` is compiled without the need for a temporary variable/cpu-register.

You can make Variants faster by using special handing for common cases:

```
if TVarData(Left).VType = TVarData(Right).VType then
begin
  case TVarData(Left).VType of
    varSingle:
      begin
        TVarData(Left).VSingle := TVarData(Left).VSingle + TVarData(Right).VSingle * M;
        Exit;
      end;
    varDouble:
      begin
        TVarData(Left).VDouble := TVarData(Left).VDouble + TVarData(Right).VDouble * M;
        Exit;
      end;
  end;
end;
 // use the slow function for all other cases
_VarAdd(Left, Right * M);
```

Comment: Variants are never going to work out as an efficient way to perform arithmetic. The suggestions here just prolong the agony.

Comment: Strange thing: VarAdd, VarSub and other 2-arguments routines work, but VarOp doesn't, 'undeclared identifier'. I don't need it anyway, just curious, what's the difference? <br> Great progress, my variants (physical units + complex numbers somewhere) were 200 times slower than doing all the same with real numbers, and now with _VarAdd etc - only 25 times slower :) it's all I needed in fact, it seems obvious that bottlenecks should be dealt with simple types only, but some noncritical code will do fine.

Comment: _VarOp is a unit private function (no interface declaration).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use clean syntax like:

```
Left := Left + Right*multiplier;
```

then you have to let the compiler generate the code. And since you are using variants, the generated code will perform appallingly badly.

If you want to call a function directly to perform the operation, then there's no point in using variants. You can create a type, presumably a record, add some methods to the type, and call those methods directly.

However, if you want to make a type that supports mathematical operators, and you care about performance, then you should use [operator overloading on records](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)).

Comment: I want to have clean syntax in programs, but the lib implementing these custom variants could be as ugly as it can, if it make it work a little faster.  Point is: use variants for input/output data, so user can write '220 V' or '(1+5i) Ohm' or '5 a.u.' and so on, and program will provide output data in most appropriate units. Some initial stuff could be performed easily, like turning all the data to dimensionless, but all inner cycles are strictly real of course.

Comment: You can do all of this efficiently with operator overloading. Variants will never yield efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for information, it's really good cause for me to move from good ol' delphi 7 and try something more recent :)

Comment: Of course the question doesn't mention Delphi 7. But variants are really no use to you. If you are going to call things like `_varAdd` then what's the point of using variants? Create your own type and call its functions directly.

Comment: I often need to make some computations at work, they're heavy enough so matlab or another math applications would take considerable time, but are executed pretty quickly on delphi since it actually compiles programs to machine code, so it's even OK for me to have slowdown, but what's really important is to have easily-written and self-explaining code, which, yes, won't contain _varAdd and so on, and could use mix of scalars (floating-point) and vectors with units attached, with near-math notation.

Comment: Well, I write code like that all the time in Delphi with operator overloading

Comment: MATLAB is often very efficient so long as you are operating on larger arrays. For work on scalars then mex files probably needed.

Comment: So _varAdd with company are to be used in custom variant implementation, I'll have to suffer once to make its work stable and relatively fast and then 'forget this nightmare' and just use all possible variants in neat little computation programs. I think I chose variants after watching VarComplex implementation, it was good example to implement another variants like vector and PhysUnits, and now it would be really interesting to try the same on operators overloading.